# Download File on export button click. Javascript __doPostBack function

Tags: casperjs

I have tried every example that has to do with this on the web it seems like but nothing has worked. I need to click an export button that downloads an xls file. Here is my casper code. Please help. Thanks!

```
casper.thenClick('#dnn_ctr623_ServiceJobsQueue_lnkExport', function() {
casper.capture('data2.png');
});

casper.on('resource.received', function (resource) {
    "use strict";
    if (resource.url.indexOf("&nbsp") !== -1) {
        var url, file;
        url = resource.url;
        file = 'monitest.xls';
        try {
            this.echo("Attempting to download file " + file);
                casper.download(resource.url, file, "GET");
        } catch (e) {
            this.echo(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the __doPostBack function:

```
 <a id="dnn_ctr623_ServiceJobsQueue_lnkExport" class="menulinksStyle" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr623$ServiceJobsQueue$lnkExport','')" style="color:Green">Export</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it never actually gets into the if statement. What am I doing wrong on the if (resource.url.indexof("&nbsp") !== -1) line where its not finding the resource. Thanks!